# Splitting equilateral triangle into 5 equal parts

Tags: geometry, dissection

Is it possible to divide an equilateral triangle into 5 equal (i.e., obtainable
from each other by a rigid motion) parts?

Comment: Does "reflection" count as [rigid motion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RigidMotion.html)?

Comment: I think it does not leave the arrangement of triangle angles unchanged so no.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might want to look at:

http://www.michaelbeeson.com/research/papers/TriangleTiling1.pdf

and the references given there.

Comment: In particular, look at the pinwheel tiling, which is for right triangles. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinwheel_tiling

Comment: Umm. I was looking a solution for equilateral triangle so how right triangle helps me?

Comment: It seems that, according to Theorem 7 (on page 116) of the reference given by Joseph Malkevitch, the answer to your question is "no."

Comment: http://www.michaelbeeson.com/research/papers/TriangleTiling1.pdf#page=56 (updated url)

Answer (score 23):

The answer is "yes", it is possible to divide equilateral triangle into $5$ equal parts, see the picture below which comes from here: https://ru-math.livejournal.com/831851.html

[image]

Comment: Note: one of the figures has to be reflected to match others. The OP says "I think it [reflection] does not leave the arrangement of triangle angles unchanged so no [reflection is not counted as rigid motion]."