# Cutting an equilateral triangle into $n$ equal pieces

Tags: geometry, dissection

We have an equilateral triangle and we want to cut it into $n$ equal triangular pieces.

For which $n$ is it possible?

**My Attempt**: I found these possible numbers: $2,3,4,6$. I also proved every $n$ of the form $4^n$.

**Note**: I don't mean equal areas, I mean equal triangles.

Comment: By equal do you mean congruent?  You can always cut it into pieces that are equal in area.  Given any $n$ for which you are successful, you can do all numbers of the form $n\cdot 4^k$ by cutting the triangle into $4^k$ equilateral triangles, then cutting each into $n$

Comment: All $n$ of the form $k^2$ would do. So would $2k^2$, and probably many more. Your findings leave 5 as the smallest unknown number; turns out that [it kinda can be done](http://ru-math.livejournal.com/831851.html), too! (The text is in Russian, but you don't really need it; the picture pretty much says it all. Yes, the pieces are not connected, but still congruent.)

Comment: Previously: [Splitting equilateral triangle into 5 equal parts](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/8288/856)

Comment: Do you mean congruent pieces or do you also require that the pieces be triangles?

Comment: no it should be triangle

Comment: Then the allowed values of $n$ seem to be limited to $k^2,\;2k^2,\;3k^2,\text{ and }6k^2$.

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A083854.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Michael Beeson has a series of papers on tiling triangles by smaller congruent triangles listed [here](http://www.michaelbeeson.com/research/papers/), of which a recent one dealing with the equilateral case is [here](http://www.michaelbeeson.com/research/papers/TriangleTilingEquilateral.pdf).

In it, it is shown that an equilateral triangle can be tiled by $N$ congruent triangles when $N$ is of the form $m^2, 2m^2, 3m^2,$ or $6m^2$. Shockingly, these are *not* the only possibilities! Among others, the case $N=109345=3^7\cdot 5$ is possible, and shown in the paper; for convenience, I'll reproduce the diagram below.

[image]

However, it is proven that no prime $N$ beyond $N=2,3$ are possible.

The paper also shows that the question of whether $N$ tiles are possible is computable, though the given algorithm is not efficient enough to make a search over large $N$ tractable.