# Dividing an equilateral triangle into N equal (possibly non-connected) parts

Tags: geometry, dissection

It’s easy to divide an equilateral triangle into $n^2$, $2n^2$, $3n^2$ or $6n^2$ equal triangles.

But can you divide an equilateral triangle into 5 congruent parts? Recently M. Patrakeev [found](https://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.124.6.547) an awesome way to do it — see the picture below (note that the parts are non-connected — but indeed are congruent, not merely having the same area). So an equilateral triangle can also be divided into $5n^2$ and $10n^2$ congruent parts.

> **Question.** Are there any other ways to divide an equilateral triangle into congruent parts? (For example, can it be divided into 7 congruent parts?) Or in the opposite direction: can you prove that an equilateral triangle can’t be divided into $N$ congruent parts for some $N$?

[image]

(Naturally, I’ve tried to find something in the spirit of the example above for some time — but to no avail. Maybe someone can find an example using computer search?..)

I’d prefer to use finite unions of polygons as ‘parts’ and different parts are allowed to have common boundary points. But if you have an example with more general ‘parts’ — that also would be interesting.

Comment: maybe triangular numbers have some part to play?

Comment: A reference for the information you provided would make it easier to understand and possibly answer your question

Comment: Have you tried generalizing for odd $n$ based on the solution for $n=5$ that you've shown?

Comment: @John Of course I've tried! But more you look at the solution for $n=5$ more miraculous it seems: yellow, orange and green parts differ by a rotation, blue and pink differ by a reflection — and then these two groups magically fit together… After a couple of months I still have no idea how to generalise this — but maybe someone can find other examples using brute-force computer search, for example…

Comment: Fair enough; I was envisioning extending parts at the bottom somehow and laddering them up but yeah, the triangle on top can't be extended the same way.

Comment: A computer search appears prohibitive. For $n=7$, and without even including the 2-colored triangles, one needs to place $7$ sets of $7$ triangles in $49$ spots which gives about $10^{36}$ combinations. While this can certainly be reduced by considering various symmetries and obvious limits, the computation of whether a given set of triangles is congruent to another set, is not trivial. In fact, it is not obvious to me how to do this. An interesting problem, though.

Comment: Note that for a triangle with edge length $n$, there is $n^2$ miniature triangles in the triangle. This may not necessarily help, but it may do...

Comment: The five-part division was posted to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8288/splitting-equilateral-triangle-into-5-equal-parts

Comment: How did you manage to split the triangle into $10n^2$  congruent parts?

Comment: @Vosatorp n² equilateral triangles (easy) → 5n² parts (as in the picture) → 10n² parts (it's easy to split each part into two congruent figures)

Comment: @GrigoryM  I understand that $5n^2$ is easy to get, but how can each of these parts be divided into two equal parts? After all, they are disjointed and unsymmetric.

Comment: @Vosatorp it's not quite obvious, but it can be done: http://dev.mccme.ru/~merzon/visual/pic_triangle10.png

Comment: @GrigoryM  Wow, got it, thanks

Answer (score 8):

Recently Pavel Guzenko found a way to divide an equilateral triangle into 15 congruent parts (and also into 30 congruent parts).

[image: dissection]

Answer (score 7):

In a recent preprint https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.07014 M.Beeson shows how to  divide an equilateral triangle into $15×3^6=10935$ equal triangles (with sides 3, 5, 7 and one angle equal to $2\pi/3$).

[image: 10935 triangles]

Answer (score 3):

In [this MathOverflow thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267095/can-a-row-of-five-equilateral-triangles-tile-a-big-equilateral-triangle), there are dissections with $5n^2$ pieces for all $n\ge 6$ where the pieces are simply connected quadrilaterals. The smallest such is pictured here:

[image]

In the thread, it is mentioned that Michael Reid claims to have found a simply-connected dissection using $7n^2$ trapezoids for some $n$, but the result appears not to be published anywhere.

In the case where the tiles are triangles, the 1995 paper [*Tilings of Triangles*](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82351337.pdf) by M. Laczkovich has many important results. In particular, it states that there is a dissection of an equilateral triangle into $2469600=2^5\cdot3^2\cdot5^2\cdot 7^3$ triangles with side lengths $7, 8,$ and $13$.

In general, Theorem 3.3 in the paper states

> Let $x$ and $y$ be non-zero integers such that $x+2y\neq 0\neq y+2x$. Then there is  a positive integer $k$ such that the equilateral triangle can be dissected into $n=|xy(x+2y)(y+2x)k^2|$ congruent triangles.

This yields dissections with a number of triangles whose squarefree part is any of $ 5, 6, 10, 13, 14, 15, 21, 30, 35, 39, 55, 65, 66, 70, 85, 95, 105, 119, 130,\ldots$