# When can we prove statements of the form "This shape cannot be decomposed into $k$ congruent pieces"?

Tags: geometry, dissection

Dissection problems tend to be pretty hard; for instance, to my knowledge we don't know whether it's possible to dissect an equilateral triangle into $k$ disjoint congruent regions for any $k$ whose squarefree part is not 2, 3, 5, or 6.

As [the example for $k=5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8288/splitting-equilateral-triangle-into-5-equal-parts) shows, questions of congruent dissection like this are not at all obvious, so assertions that a given dissection is impossible are perhaps hard to trust without rigorous proof.

However, I don't have a good sense of what techniques are available for such questions. Are we able to easily characterize, for instance, those shapes which have a dissection into two congruent regions? Are there proof methods that yield at least partial negative results in some cases? How tractable are problems like this, in general? Even a pointer to a single impossibility result for congruent dissections (perhaps under some restrictions, e.g. polygonal regions) would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this question:
[Dividing an equilateral triangle into N equal (possibly non-connected) parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1838617/dividing-an-equilateral-triangle-into-n-equal-possibly-non-connected-parts).
One of the answers is a dissection into 15 or 30 congruent parts, and 10 congruent parts is also possible:
[http://dev.mccme.ru/~merzon/visual/pic_triangle10.png](http://dev.mccme.ru/%7Emerzon/visual/pic_triangle10.png). I am unsure about 7 parts.

Comment: I'm not looking for unusual cases of *possible* dissections, but for cases that have been proven impossible - I don't think this answer addresses the title question. (But you should include the 10 piece case as a comment or answer in the first link - it doesn't seem mentioned elsewhere!)