# Dividing an equilateral triangle into equal parts

Tags: geometry, triangles, combinatorial-geometry, dissection

For which $n$ is it possible to divide an equilateral triangle into $n$ equal (i.e., obtainable from each other by a rigid motion) parts?

It is easy to come up with a partition for $n \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 6\}$. Also very easy to come up with a partition into $k^2$ equal equilateral triangles(you need to build a triangular grid). It follows that if we can build a partition into $n$ equal parts, then we can also build a partition into $nk^2$ for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

It is also well known that Mikhail Patrakeev [invented](https://ru-math.livejournal.com/831851.html) the division into $5$ equal parts.

So my question is, what is known about the remaining $n$ that are not represented as $ck^2$, where $c \in \{1, 2, 3, 5, 6\}$ (It is $7, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 17...$ parts)? Is there any other known division? Is it proved for some $n$ that there is no corresponding partition into $n$ equal parts?

Comment: I guess there should be some constraint on the "parts", e.g. should they be measurable? But it's already a very interesting question. One might ask the same question for e.g. squares or basically any shape.

Comment: Oh, yes, this is it, but I don't understand how they were able to divide the triangle into $10n^2$ equal parts.

Comment: This question has been closed, but I wanted to note that I have added [a new answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1838617/dividing-an-equilateral-triangle-into-n-equal-possibly-non-connected-parts/4045951) on the duplicate question from 2016; squarefree parts of $5,6,10,13,14,15,21,30,35,39,55,65,66,70,\ldots$ are all possible using triangular pieces.