# Can the following figures be divided into 6 equal parts?

Tags: geometry, polyomino, dissection

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4344411/can-a-figure-be-divided-into-2-and-3-but-not-6-equal-parts) asks whether a figure can be divided into $2$ and $3$ equal parts, but not $6$. It is in turn based off of [an earlier puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112648/dissecting-a-figure-into-2-3-4-and-5-parts-but-not-6) question. One natural approach is to consider the case where we have a dissection of a symmetric shape into $3$ equal parts, each of which is an asymmetric polyomino. Using, as [this site](https://userpages.monmouth.com/%7Ecolonel/oddities/index.html) does, the term "oddity" to refer to "a symmetrical figure made of an odd number of copies of a polyomino", this particular case is that of minimum oddities composed of $3$ polyominoes.

The main question is thus whether any minimum oddities of $3$ polyominoes *cannot* be dissected into $6$ equal parts. Two examples of such oddities for which I do not know the answer, taken directly from the last-mentioned site, are presented in the picture below (the sole minimum oddity of $3$ tetrominos is excluded, as that tetromino can be easily dissected into $2$ equal rectangles.)

[image]

As per the linked question, equality of parts is based on [rigid transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_transformation). While the original poster's comment indicates that the whole shape must be simply connected, the dissected parts are not specified to be; any solution regardless of connectedness is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you permit arbitrary connectedness of pieces, any polyomino is easy: simply let one piece be the $1\times 1/6$ rectangle at the bottom sixth of each square, and each subsequent piece is translated up by $1/6$ from the previous. This of course generalizes to any number of pieces.

Enforcing nice connectivity requirements makes the problem much harder in general; I have at least verified that in neither case can the polyomino be tiled by six $10$-ominoes when it is scaled up by a factor of $2$, but this is not much evidence. It's possible that more complicated connected solutions do exist, though.